# Precompiling .js.erb files for karma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Testing angular via karma/ jasmine.
Karma complains of following:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module ... is not available`

I've looked at [angular error doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0)

I believe this has something to do with precompiling `.js.erb` files.

more detail receiving this error on every test:

```
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMock due to:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$rAFProvider
```

Comment: Have you included all your app files in karma config. If yes, check the browser console logs, are all files loaded. You can verify this in source tab of chrome.

Comment: I have a suspicion, based on other reports that this is a versioning error. I've included modules in the proper fashion.